# Maximum value of $x^2+y^2$

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

*Question*

> Find the maximum value of $x^2+y^2$ if
>   $4x^4+9y^4=64$

Now I really don't understand how to proceed or whether I should change my approach all together. Any help is appreciated.Thanks :)

Comment: Do you know of the method of Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: $(2x^2+3y^2)(2x^2-3y^2)=4 x^4 - 9 y^4.$ You typed $4 x^4 + 9 y^4.$

Comment: but it is $$4x^4+9y^4$$!!!

Comment: That was a stupid mistake.sorry:/

Comment: @Shash you should keep your attemps even if they have errors. It is important so that people in the future will not have the same mistakes when looking to the same problem. And this seams a 'do it for me' question without your attempt, but this is a good interesting question (+1)

Comment: Oh ok . I'll make sure I'll keep my progress next time. Thank you for the tip:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WLOG, $2x^2=8\cos t,3y^2=8\sin t$ where $0\le t\le\frac\pi2$

Comment: wow smart thinking!!

Answer (score 2):

$$4x^4+9y^4=64$$

$$\frac{(x^2)^2}{4^2}+\frac{(y^2)^2}{(8/3)^2}=1$$

Let $x=\pm \sqrt{4\cos(\theta)}$ and $y=\pm \sqrt{\frac{8}{3} \sin (\theta)}$.  With $\theta \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Then,

$x^2+y^2=4\cos (\theta)+\frac{8}{3} \sin (\theta)$

$$=\langle 4, \frac{8}{3} \rangle \cdot \langle \cos (\theta), \sin (\theta) \rangle$$

$$=\sqrt{4^2+(\frac{8}{3})^2} \cos \left( \theta-\arctan(\frac{\frac{8}{3}}{4}) \right)$$

Because $\arctan(\frac{8}{12}) \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$. A maximum of,

$$\sqrt{4^2+(\frac{8}{3})^2}$$

Is achievable.

Comment: @Ahmed, Have u tried to show how I've parameterized $x^2, y^2$?

Comment: When you were writing yours I was thinking for a long time. I think it will be a good complement @labbhattacharjee